# programmable timer / clock generator

Tags: oscillator, clock, timer, 555

I need to generate a square wave / clock with configurable frequency between say 60 to 500Hz.
There are not stringent requirements on the frequency stability.
I need to be able to modulate this frequency at run time periodically (say once every few seconds) using an external uC using either GPIO or I2C.
I have looked at programmable oscillators and programmable alarm ICs and have yet to find any that can do what I want. I am OK with having a roll your own type of circuit for this as long as it's not super complicated.

The purpose of this is to provide timing control to some external power FETs which will switch a regulated DC voltage on and off. I don't want this switching to be halted if the software running on the uC dies for some reason. So I want an external IC to control the switching.

Can you recommend a circuit that can meet my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most microcontrollers have a PMW/Counter logic block available that runs independently of the CPU. Check the datasheet to see if that's available on your micro, it's free and easy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your mentioning of the uC's PWM controller made me look into some PWM expander ICs and these also look like a viable option.
There is post discussing these here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277848/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pwm-expander-like-there-is-a-gpio-expander