# Atmega328 datasheet recommending against toggling pins in an interrupt

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

I'm making a motor driver that has too many PWM outputs to use hardware PWM, so my intent was to generate waveforms with a "tickless" timer scheme, as follows:

```
scheduled restack:
   for i in (pwm channels)
      stack in ascending order all pwm channels
   set OCR0A = lowest PWM channel
   

OC0A ISR:
   toggle GPIO of lowest PWM channel
   pop next PWM channel off stack
   set OCR0A = next lowest PWM channel
   if list is empty
       schedule a restack
```

This is, at most, 10 or so instructions in the ISR. At 16khz TCNT, this is worst case 16khz interrupts (255 PWM channels each spaced by one count), and usual case, probably around 500Hz, which I think this microcrontroller should have no issues handling. However, from the datasheet:

> The output compare unit can be used to generate interrupts at some given time. Using the output compare to generate
> waveforms in normal mode is not recommended, since this will occupy too much of the CPU time.

Is the proposed solution bad practice? From a purely CPU usage perspective, it seems totally within limits, despite what the datasheet says.

Comment: Note [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277848/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pwm-expander-like-there-is-a-gpio-expander#277851) is a question about PWM expansion, might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks - that's definitely good to know for the future. Unfortunately I've already re-rolled the hardware enough times and I don't want to do it again for just a hobby project

Comment: that's an interesting way to do it. not recommended but possible (with serious limitations). how many channels? what pwm period? what mcu clock? what resolution? any other time critical activities taking place (e.g. serial rx)?

Comment: Serialrx is going to be going on. I'm thinking of a 256 prescaler on clock0, which leaves me with a ~250hz pwm, and gives me a minimum of 256 clock cycles to handle everything in the ISR. At the moment only 3 pwm channels, but it will increase in the future. What's the "right" way to do this if it's more than the available hardware pwm channels?

Comment: "what's the right way?" - besides different hardware (obv)? I can't think of one. Having the interrupt cycle thru a list of (pin_mask, counter_value) pairs isn't that bad, actually. you could have the timer overflow interrupt reset everything.

Comment: The overflow interrupt will set all the (nonzero) pairs high. I'm worried I can't enumerate the list in time in the overflow interrupt - I'd have to walk through and rebuild the stack. That could be hundreds of instructions

Comment: it would only have to get rebuilt (i.e. sorted) when you change it. actually another special case is if two pwm's would have the same value // i mean there are a lot of details to work out, it's very old school

Comment: Good point - I can rebuild the list when I get input from the serial device (which is controlling this), and also avoid possibly missing serial. Also I'd have to continue checking until I need to change OCR0A. I love old school programming

Comment: what I imagined was, the main code sets up the list (circular list)  whenever, but might have to carefully time the act of updating the copy of the list seen by the interrupt (in fact the overflow interrupt itself can do this with a new-data-ready flag), the OC interrupt doing the work increments an index into this list, and the overflow interrupt resets the index to 0....

Comment: (and just to be totally clear, hardware with more timers is cheap and preferable. you would do this if you enjoy the challenge of it...)

Comment: That's also smart - uses more memory to maintain effectively two lists, but it works. I'm totally up for the challenge, and I've already got the PCBs in the mail, so the hardware is staying the same. Appreciate the input!

Comment: How many simultaneous PWM channels do you _really_ need?

Comment: At the moment, between 2 and 9. I'm also trying to do this in a more expansion-capable method instead of writing code that only addresses the exact use case I have and would need major restructuring to fix it. Maybe I've been poisoned by my work environment where all the code was written in the 80s, but this seems like a more future-proof method of doing it