# I2C to 100+ PWM

Tags: pwm, i2c, components

I'm currently looking for some sort of interface which can generate many (up to 100 potentially) individual PWM outputs. I figure I2C is the best way to go about this, but I'm open to other possibilities.

The only thing I've found so far is the Adafruit PCA9685, but at $15 a pop ($105 for the 7 I'd need,) I'm open to other options.

I don't have particularly high needs in terms of frequency or resolution - a step resolution of 1% (7 bit, I guess), at 10 ms time resolution at 1 Hz update rate would be my lower bounds on performance.

Comment: Do any of the answers to [Is there such a thing as a PWM expander like there is a GPIO expander](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277848/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pwm-expander-like-there-is-a-gpio-expander) help?

Comment: Those ICs Adafruit uses are pretty inexpensive for the number of channels (about 15 cents/channel USD in 100 chip qty). You could put them on your own PCB. I think the connectors and whatever you're driving with it are going to dominate unless it's LEDs, in which case there are more specialized ICs for that purpose. Of course you could do it all in one chip using an FPGA but that learning curve is steep.

Comment: PCA9685 is current less than 3 dollars a chip on digikey for 16 channels. Hard to imagine you're going to get much cheaper than 25 dollars for something like this. Assuming specs are ok, could drop 6 or 7 on an Arduino shield or whatever format you want easily enough.

Comment: interesting things happen if you disconnect the VDD of a 4017

Comment: @AndrewMorton I did come across this question myself; I found that it did help a bit, but I wasn't sure how to extend the suggestions there to the scale I need

Comment: out of curiosity, what is this setup used for? maybe there are some workarounds for it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I did have the idea of just printing my own PCB with the ICs Adafruit uses, but after shipping costs and all included, it would've worked out to about the same price for more work.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad The setup is that I have 100 or so low-resistance resistors (heating elements, really) which I need to operate at realtime-updated voltages. I'm currently going to be using the PWM signals on power MOSFETs. I also have other peripherals involved, so my pins are a bit limited

Comment: @DavisLast Yeah, but I thought it was you who made the edits or I would not have approved it. It has been rolled back

Comment: For 100 heating elements, does your duty cycle allow fewer higher power mosfets and switch them in a 10x10 grid instead? (or 16x7 to take advantage of the chip)

Comment: @PeteKirkham If I'm understanding you correctly (16 groups of 7 heating elements), no - I require individual control.

Comment: What do you need the PWM outputs to control?  If you're using PWM to control devices for which a maximum duty cycle of e.g. 25% would be acceptable (drive with higher power/current while it's on), it might be possible to reduce cost enormously.

Comment: @supercat How would I be able to do this? I could probably make 25% work pretty easily with a few small changes.

Comment: @DavisLast: To achieve 96 channels, use 24 variable-pulse width outputs and twelve 74HC139 chips.  Wire all of the A and B inputs together to two select outputs, and wire the 24 /G pins to the variable pulse-width outputs.  Select AB=00, then output a pulse of suitable length for the first 24 channels on each of the 24 outputs, then select AB=01, output a pulse of suitable length for the next 24 channels, etc.

Comment: @DavisLast multiplexing is still individual control, rather than running say 10V for 100% dute run 25V for 14% cycle and switch between 7 banks during the larger cycle.. Supercat is explaining much the same thing

Comment: Can you say more about the heating elements? Current, voltage, resistance, if possible datasheet... Have you purchased them already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to using SPI, multiple chains of SPI devices can do this, with a more straightforward driver than I2C. As a bonus, SPI will offer you faster updates than you can achieve with I2C. If your host can do multi-bit SPI, even better.

Adafruit themselves have a [12-channel, 16-bit PWM board for $7.50](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1455) which is a bit more affordable than the PCA9685 version.

A possibly even cheaper approach, but with more intense CPU overhead, is to implement the PWM directly with shift registers with something like the 74HC595. With this approach the SPI runs all the time, and you implement PWM by controlling the duty cycle in software. Since SPI uses a fixed frequency clock the PWM timing is deterministic.

More here: https://hackaday.com/2011/11/05/controlling-shift-registers-via-spi/

And here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/software-pwm-using-daisy-chained-74hc595s-spi/38251

TI offers a shift-register style LED driver with built-in current references, saving you the trouble of individual LED resistors. If you only need one color (or use separate R,G,B drivers) then is is a good option: https://www.ti.com/product/TLC59284

Comment: The other comments have some very valid answers, but this is what I've arrived on personally - I have an idea that, for me, using GPIO for chip select with these SPI-based boards is the way to go.

Comment: Worth noting that the chip on the adafruit board costs about $3 on mouser, which is a difference of about $31, getting your own PCB manufactured to house the chips (plus the passives needed for it) will probably cost you less than that.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the most capable solution in a single IC is an FPGA or a CPLD.

Cheap parts can easily handle 100 PWM outputs, or as many as it has I/O pins for. You can add an SPI interface to control it, which is simpler than I2C and just as practical for a point-to-point connection.

You'd need to be able to design the firmware for it in VHDL or Verilog, which are straightforward to learn and well documented on the internet. You can use the manufacturer's free development tools to simulate and compile your design. You'll find plenty of low-cost demo' boards you can try out or rig up, with varying amounts of I/O pins.

An FPGA/CPLD is more expensive per part than a microcontroller but there's parts for £5 that can easily do this. And an FPGA/CPLD is far more capable at this sort of task than a microcontroller and much easier to design for it (said from the perspective of being able to do both).

Answer (score 4):

Use a PLD, that will probably be the best thing. You'll have to do some HDL, but it would give you the GPIO. Another option is a high GPIO count MCU; the PWM could be bit banged at the rates you have without too much trouble.

Comment: Regarding the bit-banging option... an MCU with a DMA engine would be great at triggering GPIO value changes en masse from a hardware timer.

Comment: You probably wouldn't need that if you didn't want precise timing. But its really a hardware timer with interrupts that you'd need. Even low end MCU's that are cheap and running at 10's of MHz would be plenty for 10ms resolution. If you need more resolution and a high update rate (like better than 1ms and 100Hz update) then you'd need a really fast MCU like in the 100's of MHz. An FPGA/PLC would give you exact timing, as fast as the clock, but is more expensive in time it takes to program and hardware cost.

Comment: I could be mistaken on the PLC thing then I'll edit.

Comment: PLD - Programmable Logic *Device* :) PLC is an industrial computer with industrial I/O, more or less.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a peripheral, but... 8x RP2040's is $5.6, each can do 14 PWM's using 7 timers.
(one of them is for i2c)

Or even cheaper, do the PWM in software, because why not?
Then you can do 28 PWM channels per chip, say 5 chips, $3.5.